# Named groups in Django based off model field?

Tags: regex, django, django-models, django-views

I was trying to replicate a url regex equivalent to:

```
url(r'^members/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'profiles.views.single'),
```

While I understand I am taking the users that exist within my database from:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

I am wondering if I can change this to something a little more unique. I've been reading the documentation from: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial04/ but am still lost.

My question is regarding whether or not I can use data from a model as the named group in the regex expression.

Example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    unique_code = models.IntegerField(max_length = 5)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
```

Is it somehow possible to use that 'unique_code' field as a possible url in my regex to map like:

```
 url(r'^members/(?P<unique_code>\w+)/$', 'profiles.views.single'),
```

I was trying something like this, but it obviously didn't work:

```
def single(request, unique_id):
    try:
        uid = get_object_or_404(Address, unique_id=unique_id)
        final = uid
    except:
        raise Http404

    return render_to_response('single_user.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace unique_id in your function with unique_code

```
def single(request, unique_code):
try:
    uid = get_object_or_404(Address, unique_code=unique_code)
    final = uid
except:
    raise Http404

return render_to_response('single_user.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: It worked! I've literally been working hours to get this! Thanks!